# Does Skype work better through Chrome than through desktop app on the M1 chip?

Tags: google-chrome, skype

I heard that Skype for desktop uses node.js. However it seems like all node.js apps for now run as Intel apps.

But since node.js is based on Chrome, and Chrome runs natively on m1, is it more efficient to run all these node.js apps through chrome, rather than node.js?

Comment: Skype is hardly a high performance app. I'm not sure what difference it would make.

Comment: Peace of mind, cause it's native.

Comment: Not sure how that instills peace of mind. tbh, I've run Skype a lot on a new M1 iMac & never even cared to look. One would imagine they'll soon rewrite it for ARM, everybody else is doing, gradually. In the meantime it appears to make no practical difference.

Comment: @Tetsujin what is there to rewrite? All they have to do is package it with the m1 version of node.js.

Comment: Isn't node.js simply for the 'plugin' API? I don't think it has anything to do with the app itself. I don't get why anyone would write a Mac native app  that way. The needs re-writing for ARM, the same as every app will eventually need re-writing for ARM. In the meantime, it works absolutely fine under Rosetta2.